# VB.NET ListView OwnerDraw Subitems disappear on hovering

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a problem with the ListView ownerdrawing. Whenever I hover over a ListViewItem, the subitems of them disappears. When I click on it again, they appear again, and then they stay visible. That only happens one time, at the beginning. This is my current code:

```
Private Sub ListView1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawItem

If (e.State And ListViewItemStates.Selected) <> 0 Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Violet, e.Bounds)

        Dim cBounds As Rectangle = e.Bounds
        cBounds.X = cBounds.X + 6

        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, New Font("Segoe UI", 9.25, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.White, cBounds)
    Else
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 25, 25, 25)), e.Bounds)

        Dim cBounds As Rectangle = e.Bounds
        cBounds.X = cBounds.X + 6

        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, New Font("Segoe UI", 9.25), Brushes.White, cBounds)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_DrawSubItem(sender As Object, e As DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DrawSubItem
    If (e.ItemState And ListViewItemStates.Selected) <> 0 Then
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Violet, e.Bounds)

        Dim cBounds As Rectangle = e.Bounds
        cBounds.X = cBounds.X + 6

        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, New Font("Segoe UI", 9.25, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.White, cBounds)
    Else
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 25, 25, 25)), e.Bounds)

        Dim cBounds As Rectangle = e.Bounds
        cBounds.X = cBounds.X + 6

        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, New Font("Segoe UI", 9.25), Brushes.White, cBounds)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you posted does not reproduce that problem.  Do you have any code in the MouseHover event, or other mouse events?

Answer (score 3):

> Because of a bug in the underlying Win32 control, the DrawItem event occurs without accompanying DrawSubItem events once per row in the details view when the mouse pointer moves over the row, causing anything painted in a DrawSubItem event handler to be painted over by a custom background drawn in a DrawItem event handler.

See the note in remarks [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawitem.aspx) for 2 workarounds.